# How do I batch convert multiple csv files into txt files?

Tags: r

I was wondering if there is a method to quickly convert multiple .csv files into tab-delimited format, and also simultaneously remove the first row (i.e. first observation) under the column headings?

Answer (score 1):

An option is to get the files from the working directory

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
```

then read the files into a `list`, remove the first row and write as `.txt` file

```
lapply(files, function(x) {
             dat <- read.csv(x)[-1,]
             newname <- sub("\\.csv", ".txt", basename(x))
             write.table(dat, newname, sep="\t")
          })

    })
```